# Running shell script as a cron on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I've written a simple script date.sh in /home/user/test

```
date -u > file.txt
```

This should write the current date and time in file.txt. I've given it the necessary access right with `chmod +x date.sh`. When I run the script from the terminal it works fine and updates the time in the text file.

But when I run it as a cron

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/user/test/date.sh
```

I don't see the dates changing in file.txt
As my knowledge about this is limited at the time, my question is, how can I run the date.sh script as a cronjob

Answer (score 1):

Try providing a full output file path in the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
date -u > /home/user/test/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with date.sh, it should **NOT** be `date > file.txt`
All the files should contain their entire path. In this case the script should be

```
date > /home/user/test/file.txt
```

Comment: And you surely mean `file.txt` as target, as the output of `date` is not executable shell code. The answer by Jeslin has it right after some improvement.